# Style is not always applied with nested tables

Tags: css, html-table

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stenci/baxrd2e4/) contains a table with 4 nested tables.

The borders on the table in the first row are not collapsed, so I assume that nested tables do not inherit styles from their parent tables.

The borders on the table in the second row are collapsed, because of `td.small table`. Good.

But the padding on the `td` on the same row is not 0, as it should be because of `td.small`. Bad.

I thought the styles declared at the end of the css file and in the innermost element should be the ones applied. The `td` containing the `table` on the second row has `class="small"`, which is defined at the end of the css, but its `padding` doesn't apply.

On the fourth row there are both the style and the explicit style attribute applied to the `td`, and in that case it works.

Why isn't the second row table rendered with zero padding?
And why is the last one rendered with zero padding?

Comment: I'm REALLY confused about what you're TRYING to do here. You have `td.small table` padding rules, and then you have another padding rule for `td.small`. Which padding do you want and where?

Comment: Regardless of its usefulness, the behavior should follow some logic, and I would like to understand it.

Comment: If THAT'S what you're asking: http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `table.large td` rule is overriding the `td.small` rule because its selector has two element names and one class name, whereas `td.small` has one element name and one class name. An easy way around this would be:

```
td.small {
    padding: 0em !important;
}
```

Alternatively, you could add more elements/classes to the `td.small` selector.

[More information on selector priority](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity)

Comment: I'm getting into more complex html and css, and I didn't know about the specificity. At first glance it looks like a way to make it less intuitive and less predictable. It looks like the behavior of one page could change just because one decides to add one name to an old rule.